# Format text for word output while using rmd template

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown

I want to be able to format the word output (html output or pdf output works fine with html and LaTeX, respectively) while using the papaja template for word.

As an example, let's say I want to start a paper with an epigraph, where the first line contains someone's quote (left-aligned, without indent) and the second line contains the quoted person's name (right-aligned):

[image: example formatting]

The following gives me APA formatting thanks to papaja (as desired) and a word document with the styles "left" and "right".

````
---
title: Test
author:
- name: author
  email: author@uni.com
  address: address
  corresponding: yes
output:
  papaja::apa6_word 
---


```{r message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library("papaja")
```


<div custom-style="left">This text should go on the left after editing the styles in word</div>

<div custom-style="right">This text should go on the right after editing the styles in word</div>
````

When I edit the styles "left" and "right" in the word document, save that document as `template.docx` and then change my output to include the template as reference (see MWE below), the first lines are correctly formatted (aligned to the left and right). However, as I did not specify that I want to use papaja's apa6_word template, the output is logically not formatted in APA style.

````
---
title: Test
author:
- name: author
  email: author@uni.com
  address: address
  corresponding: yes
output: 
    word_document:
      reference_docx: template.docx
---


```{r message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library("papaja")
```

<div custom-style="left">This text should go on the left after editing the styles in word</div>

<div custom-style="right">This text should go on the right after editing the styles in word</div>
````

**Is there a way to get both? I.e., leave the formatting to `papaja::apa6_word` but be able to fine-tune some aspects?** Hacks specific to this question would already be a help, but as I anticipate to encounter this problem more often, I was wondering whether there was a more general solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. With the latest development version of `papaja` (`devtools::install_github("crsh/papaja@devel")`) you can provide a custom reference DOCX file to `apa6_word`. So, in you example, instead of `word_document` you can use `apa6_word`:

```
output:
  papaja::apa6_word:
    reference_docx: template.docx
```

Comment: This is so great, thanks! I can let papaja do all the formatting and if I need something special I can still implement this programmatically.